# How to add to a List<string> an object that might be a single string or a list of strings

Tags: c#, reflection

Looks like this has been answered for python, but not C#, and since I'm python illiterate and new at C#, here goes:

I'm trying to get a property from a instance of a class (Task/task) based on a enum parameter (type) and add the property to a List.  The tricky part is that I'm not sure if the property value is going to be a string or a list of strings.

So, generally I'm looking at something like:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Task).GetProperty(type.ToString());
List<string> values = new List<string>();
```

then something I know doesn't work when the value is a List, but illustrates my intent:

```
values.Add((string)propertyInfo.GetValue(task, null));
```

What are my options?

Comment: I have to ask, why are you using reflection to pull data out of a Task instance? Surely you could just use its properties directly?

Comment: @AshleyRoss Good question.  I'm trying to minimize my code length/complexity and to enable the code to handle changes (added/removed properties) in the Task class.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were using the [System.Threading.Tasks.Task class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), not your own custom class named Task. Still, I would be wary of dynamic code like this, as you lose all the benefits of C#'s type checking, etc.; it's fairly rare that it is really required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`PropertyInfo.PropertyType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx) to check the type of the property - or you could just fetch the value as `object` and go from there:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(task, null);
if (value is string)
{
    values.Add((string) value);
}
else if (value is IEnumerable<string>)
{
    values.AddRange((IEnumerable<string>) value);
}
else
{
    // Do whatever you want if the type doesn't match...
}
```

Or instead of using `is` and casting, you can use `as` and check the result against null:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(task, null);
string stringValue = value as string;
if (stringValue != null)
{
    values.Add(stringValue);
}
else
{
    IEnumerable<string> valueSequence = value as IEnumerable<string>;
    if (valueSequence != null)
    {
        values.AddRange(valueSequence);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do whatever you want if the type doesn't match...
    } 
}
```

Note that this works if the property is any other sort of sequence of strings, not just a `List<string>`. It also copies the list, so that any further changes won't affect the existing list that the property refers to. Adjust if you need to :)

One point that Lee's answer reminded me of - if it's a `string` property with a `null` value and you *want* a list with a single null element, you'll need to use `PropertyType`. For example:

```
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
{
    values.Add((string) propertyInfo.GetValue(task, null));
}
```

Comment: When you say it copies the list are you referring to AddRange? btw you are missing a parenthesis in the second example values.AddRange :)

Comment: @Ulises: Yes, I'm referring to `AddRange`.

Answer (score 5):

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Task).GetProperty(type.ToString());
List<string> values = new List<string>();

object p = propertyInfo.GetValue(task, null);
if(p is string)
{
    values.Add((string)p);
}
else if(p is List<string>)
{
    values.AddRange((List<string>)p);
}
```

alternatively you could use `as`:

```
string str = p as string;
List<string> list = p as List<string>;

if(str != null)
{
    values.Add(str);
}
else if(list != null)
{
    values.AddRange(list);
}
```

Comment: No, they *are* the same - a `null` reference isn't a `string`. Neither version would add a `null` reference to the list.